# Modelling a sphere with 2 flat faces

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model something like the object on the left side of this photo:

[image]

I need to get a shape that is basically a sphere with two flattened areas, one at the bottom and one on the side with an angle. The part I'm having trouble with is getting the shape while maintaining a clean topology.

The best base topology seems like a cylinder, I just can't find a way to deform it perfectly with the Simple Deform (Bend) + Cast (Sphere) modifiers.

Comment: so you don't need to make the central object?

Comment: no, just the one on the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a sphere with flat faces:

- Put your picture as *Background Image*.
- Create a cube and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide Smooth*.
- Cut it with the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut perpendicularly).
- Use <kbd>V</kbd> to separate the pieces you want to delete, then delete.
- Clean a bit the rim with some merge (<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>).
- Extrude to create faces, merge at center.
- Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and click *Shading* > *Smooth* to smooth.

[image]

I've tried a more detailed version, with the button holes etc... In that case a UV Sphere seems better to begin:

- Put your picture as *Background Image*.
- Create a UV Sphere (48 segments, 24 rings), keep a copy on another layer, give this copy a *Subsurf* modifier.
- Rotate your original sphere 45°. Give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the copy as *Target* so that the shape of the original will stick to a sphere shape during the next operations.
- Cut the top of your sphere, align the rim to the picture’s rim.
- Cut 2 holes on the side, extrude and scale to create 2 circles for the buttons (use <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopsTools* > *Circle*, or <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>).
- Cut the base with the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut perpendicularly).
- Apply the *Shrinkwrap* modifier.
- Make some extrudes for all these holes.
- For the sphere's « equator » make a thin bevel and extrude .
- Etc…

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a boolean modifier, as that means you don't need to change the model topology at all. Create a sphere, the create a cube and position it over the sphere such that the cube overlaps the part of the sphere to be removed. Then put a boolean modifier on the sphere and select the cube, and select 'Difference'. Select the cube and press h to hide it, and you should get a nice, clean cut out of your sphere.

See an example in the image below:
[image: bool]